# Controller Error: Do I need to worry?

Tags: windows-7, controller, atapi

I have a HP Pavillion dv5224ea Laptop with Windows 7 on it. Recently I discovered a Error in Event Viewer:

```
The driver detected a controller error on \Device\Ide\IdePort1.
```

(more details):

```
- System 

  - Provider 

   [ Name]  atapi 

  - EventID 11 

   [ Qualifiers]  49156 

   Level 2 

   Task 0 

   Keywords 0x80000000000000 

  - TimeCreated 

   [ SystemTime]  2010-03-07T12:43:07.090197600Z 

   EventRecordID 30198 

   Channel System 

   Computer Alistair-Win7 

   Security 


- EventData 

   \Device\Ide\IdePort1 
   0000100001000000000000000B0004C002000000850100C00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004100000 


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Binary data:


In Words

0000: 00100000 00000001 00000000 C004000B 
0008: 00000002 C0000185 00000000 00000000 
0010: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
0018: 00000000 00001004   


In Bytes

0000: 00 00 10 00 01 00 00 00   ........
0008: 00 00 00 00 0B 00 04 C0   .......À
0010: 02 00 00 00 85 01 00 C0   ......À
0018: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ........
0020: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ........
0028: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ........
0030: 00 00 00 00 04 10 00 00   ........
```

Event Viewer is recording A LOT of these errors (sometimes 13, one after the other!). Do I need to worry? What does this error mean? What device could "\Device\Ide\IdePort1" be? What is a ATAPI Error? Do I need to re-install Windows? I generally find the occurs when I try to backup my machine (using Windows Backup) or when using a program that uses Volume Shadow Copy. I have run "sfc", no problems. There are no Device Errors in Device Manager. I have also run "vssadmin list writers", no problems. Whats going on??? Would it be a good idea to re-install Windows 7?

Comment: Try running 'chkdsk c: /f' to see if there are any issues.

Comment: I have run chkdsk c: /f /r /b, no problems...

Comment: Windows logs everything, so if the machine is working I wouldn't worry about it. 

If the machine is hanging, my guess is that you're having an issue with either a disk drive or an optical drive, most likely. Could be a loose cable or a failing drive or maybe you need to reinstall drivers. 

Do you have any idea what kind of device you actually have installed on IDE port 1?

Comment: No, I have no idea. Anyway I can find out?

Comment: I think you should go to the laptop manufacturer's forums and ask there. The only way I know how to know for sure, other than that, would be to open it up and look.

Comment: OK, I have a look and get back to you...

Comment: Make a screenshot of this tool please and attach it.
http://crystalmark.info/software/CrystalDiskInfo/index-e.html

Answer (score 1):

First off, this seems to be an error for the second SATA port since numbering starts at 0 for computers and it specifies 'atapi' which is what SATA is based off of.

I suggest looking under the device manager to see what device is hooked onto port 1, and if it is the cd drive, don't worry about it. If it is a harddrive, keep semi-frequent backups.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should check SMART logs/information of your HDD. Just google for "smart monitoring tools windows".

If they're fine, then reinstalling Windows should help. If they aren't, maybe it's a better idea to replace HDD preventively.

Edit: also it may be caused by loose SATA connector.